# Is there a well known name for an optimal route problem with continuous vertex weight?

Tags: routing

I have the following problem. Imagine a fully connected undirected graph, and I wish to calculate the optimal route for a traveller across that graph. Each vertice can only be visited once or not at all. Each vertex visited gives a positive payoff. However, each edge has a negative cost associated with its distance. The traveller desires to maximize its profit (payoff-cost).

Is this a known problem with existing literature? The problem is clearly related to the travelling salesman, since it naturally contains a "shortest path". However, I'm yet to find a shortest path problem with continuous vertex weights and optional visitation.

The closest I found is the [Target visitation problem](https://doi.org/10.2514/6.2004-6212). But in this paper, the study uses rank as vertex weights, not actual continuous weights. Further it does assume that the traveller has to visit all vertices. So it does not quite fit the formulation.

Comment: The payoff of the vertices can be deducted in half from the cost of every edge it is an endpoint of. So only have to care aboute edge costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is NP-hard.  The [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) is a special case of this problem: put +1 payoff on each vertex, 0 payoff on each edge, then there is a path that achieves total payoff $|V|$ iff there is a Hamiltonian path in the problem.

Your problem is equivalent to the weighted [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).  First, create a new source vertex $s$, with payoff 0 and edges of cost 0 to each other vertex in the graph.  Next, transform the graph as follows: for each vertex with payoff $p$, add $p$ from the payoff of each edge that is inbound on that vertex, and zero out the payoff on that vertex.  Then you obtain a graph with payoffs on the edges and nothing on the vertices.  In this graph, the longest path starting at $s$ (measured by sum of edges in the path) in the new graph is the same as the optimal route in the original graph.  Moreover, if we pick a sufficiently large constant $C$ (e.g., larger than the sum of all edge costs), and make each edge out of $s$ have cost $C$, then the longest path in the new graph is the same as the optimal route in the original graph.

So, it follows that any algorithm for the weighted longest path problem can be used to solve your problem.